# Find a relation between $a$,$b$ and $p$ so that $f(x)=\frac 1{(1+|x|^a)(1+\left|\log x\right|^b)}\in L^p\left(\mathbb R\right)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

A question in our measure theory test reads

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that
> $$f(x)=\frac 1{\left(1+|x|^a\right)\left(1+\left|\log x\right|^b\right)}$$
> Find a relation between $a$,$b$ and $p$ so that $f\in L^p\left(\mathbb R\right)$.

Assuming
$${\large\int}_{\mathbb R} \frac{\text{d}x}{\left\{\left(1+|x|^a\right)\left(1+\left|\log x\right|^b\right)\right\}^p}<\infty$$
and doing some manipulations, I came to
$$\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{\left(1+x^a\right)^p}\right)\left(\int_1^\infty \frac{e^x\;\text{d}x}{\left(1+x^b\right)^p}\right)<\infty$$
but couldn't yield anything out of it.

How do I handle this equation?

I was suggested [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4090312/942722) by Spring, which I couldn't make much use of.

Comment: This question has been asked many many times. Use approach0 to find a duplicate.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I honestly wasn't suggested anything before submitting. Can you please put a link...

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4090312/942722) might be somewhat related. (I hope it isn't useless (=: )

Comment: @Spring thanks for the comment, but I couldn't make much use of it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I also tried with Approach0, I copy pasted the formula in the question, but with no avail. I'm not familiar with measure theory, so maybe its only me missing something _if_ the question is an abstract duplicate

Comment: Note that, for $a < A$ and $b < B$, $$ \frac{1}{x^{A} (\log x)^{B}} \ll \frac{1}{x^{A} (\log x)^{b}} \ll \frac{1}{x^{a} (\log x)^{B}} \qquad \text{as} \quad x \to \infty, $$ where $g(x)\ll h(x)$ means that $g(x), h(x) \geq 0$, and $g(x)/h(x) \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Also note that $$\int_{42}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p}<\infty\quad\iff\quad p>1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \int_{42}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(\log x)^p}<\infty\quad\iff\quad p>1.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks for the comment, but I didn't understand a word of it... :( Can you please add some more explanation? I mean, how does the first equation help? Where did $42$ come from? And how does everything you said connect with the problem I posted? You may even consider adding the details as an answer...

Comment: If you don't understand a word of my comment, chances are you are not properly prepared to study measure theory. Especially, what you are asking is based on solid understanding on calculus. And if you think you are lacking this understanding, it would be much helpful to review some calculus textbooks (especially the chapters about improper integrals). They would be much more organized and detailed than what other users would answer or comment.

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks for your comment, but I have almost completed doing a whole course on measure theory now. So, maybe I am missing something crucial in your argument. Can you please tell me more about how you got that $42$ into your comment... maybe I'll be able to connect something then...

Comment: The point is that the number $42$ is not relevant for the convergence at all; it can be replaced by any positive number without changing the answer. I simply chose [$42$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) as a *comical relief* and to hint that the choice really doesn't matter.